# Line up Font Awesome Icons to left of linked Phone No/email

Tags: css, font-awesome

Please could you tell me how to get the phone and email icons - top left on [this page](http://www.photomobil.co.il/) - to align to the left of the phone number and email address. The site is set up for RTL display - I'm wondering if that's causing the problem but not sure how to override it.  Thank you!!

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">

    <div class="pull-left">
    <?php
        if( get_option('header_phone') )
            echo '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <a href="tel:' .      get_option('header_phone') . '">'. get_option('header_phone') .'</a>';

        if( get_option('header_email') )
            echo '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="mailto:' . get_option('header_email') . '">'. get_option('header_email') .'</a>';
    ?>
```

CSS:

```
    .fa-phone:before {
    content: "\e0bf";
    float: left;
      }
   .fa-envelope:before {
    content: "\e0bf";
   float: left;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the RTL display is kinda reversing the order of things, so the icons need to be **after** the text they apply to. Then the rendered html is thus -

```html
<div class="pull-left">
  <a href="tel:545-799518  (972) 00+">545-799518  (972) 00+</a>
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 
  <a href="mailto:info@photomobil.co.il">info@photomobil.co.il</a>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick but the two items were a bit close up against each other.

Comment: You would need to fine tune your CSS a little.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inversing the text/icon order I would do this in more natural way, like:

```
<div class="pull-left" style="
    direction: ltr;
"> <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <a href="tel:545-799518  (972) 00+">545-799518  (972) 00+</a><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="mailto:info@photomobil.co.il">info@photomobil.co.il</a></div>
```

You'll se that I have explicitly changed the text direction for the container.

Comment: Oh that's just perfect!!  Thank you SO much!!